# USB host stack for PIC32

Tags: pic, android

I have a board built around a PIC32MZ that uses a FTDI 312D to communicate through tbe UART with an Android device.

What kind of software do I need on the PIC32 side so I can get rid of the FTDI and connect the PIC32 directly to the Android device? My board would be the host so the Android device can always charge from 5V my board supplies and I'd prefer not having to do a custom Android build or add up any drivers.

Comment: You appear to be answering your own question in the title of your question. The kind of software you need is a "USB host stack for PIC32"... What is your real question?

Comment: I was hoping to get a link to a repo or page or a tutorial from someone more experienced. Something to help getting it done. But it's ok, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the PIC you selected has the hardware, Microchip's own code libraries should do this for you. I did succeed in getting a PIC32 writing to a USB flash drive a few years ago. It was a bit of a fight to get working, but it did the job. These days you can probably set it up with Microchip's Harmony code generation stuff, although I haven't used it myself.